# Graph Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

What is the maximum and minimum number of edges to be considered in krushkal's algorithm with an example for both cases.

What I thought was since the Krushkal's algorithm is for finding minimum spanning tree the maximum number of edges is (V-1) where V is the number of vertices. Adding one more edge would result in a cycle in the graph. How can we obtain at a minimum value ?

Comment: Should be asked in http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

A tree of N vertices always has N-1 edges. Consequently you have to consider at least N-1 edges during Kruskal's algorithm. An example may be a graph which is a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Kruskal's algorithm stops when you've added `V - 1` edges to your MST, so this is the minimum that have to be considered. This happens when the lowest value `V - 1` edges of your graph do not form a cycle, and they will be added one after the other by the algorithm, after which it will stop.

For example, consider a complete graph with edges with cost `1`, which is minimum in the graph, between node `1` and every other node. Make all the other edges have cost `2`.

The worst case is when you must inspect every edge (of which there are `O(V^2)`) until you finally select `V - 1`. This means that you have to force a lot of cycles to be created before the last edge is added.

Consider a complete graph again. Have the `V - 2` edges between node `1` and `V - 2` nodes have cost 1, which is minimum in the graph. These will be selected first. Now let node `k` be the one that is not part of a selected edge, so that is left out of the graph. Have the edge between node `k` and node `1` have the largest cost. This will cause it to be inspected and added to the MST last, forcing the algorithm to inspect all `O(V^2)` edges before building the MST.

Remember the Kruskal's algorithm processes edges in increasing order of their cost, rejecting edges that would form a cycle if added to the MST we are building.